# DHCP server which only configures default gateway

Tags: networking, dhcp, dhcp-server

I have static ip's assigned to my machines, but no default routes. I want to send only the default gateways via a dhcp server. Is that possible?

Comment: If they are DHCP clients, then why do you only want to send the gateway?  Or are you saying that they are not DHCP clients?

Comment: They are not dhcp clients right now. They have static ips assigned

Comment: usually dhcp server are for assigning ips and routes, but i dont want to assign ips (they will come from the static ips i have assigned). I only want the dhcp server to assign the default route. I'm not sure if its possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, either the system gets it's IP information information through DHCP or not. If you really want to stick with static IP's you could make the static IP's the secondary address on the interface and have the primary IP discovered by DHCP.

That breing said, why do you go though the trouble of setting up static IPs and not just enter the gateway as well? It's one IP extra...

Comment: This is not a good recommendation, no network should ever be set up this way.

Comment: I totally agree, but what the asker is asking doesn't make much sense. However, it is a valid answer to his question.

Comment: Sure - but the value in this site is not just to the original questioner, but anyone who has a similar concern who happens across the question.  So we must be careful to state that while the answer will work, it should never be done this way.

Answer (score 3):

This is possible on linux, and unlikely to be possible on Windows and OSX - but it is the wrong approach.

The ideal approach is to use DHCP for both IP address and default route - and DNS if you use it.

You define the static addresses in your dhcp server configuration, such that a specific MAC address gets a specific IP address.  Then you can also pass them the default route and anything else you want.

This gives you the advantage of static IP addresses combined with the advantage of centrally managed IP configuration.

Comment: I know you can do it on Linux.  Less sure about Windows, OSX.

Comment: I was talking about the option of requesting a route (or other options), but not an address.  Like the OP was asking for, and I believe you said 'may' about.  You said 'may', I am saying I have used DHCP to configure a Linux host that had a static IP, not reservation.  So, I was providing conditional confirmation of your maybe.

Comment: @Zoredache Sorry, I misunderstood.  I have updated the answer with your info (you can do this yourself if you see an answer that can be edited to increase quality)